# grunt-sass error: file to import not found or unreadable: "foundation"

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I'm getting the following error when running `grunt sass`

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning: /home/max/dev/ang-news/src/scss/app.scss:2: file to import not found 
or unreadable: "foundation"
Current dir: /home/max/dev/ang-news/src/scss/
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

here is the app.scss

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

here is my Gruntfile.js `sass` task

```
sass: {
  options: {
    includedPaths: ['bower_componenets/foundation/scss'],
    sourceMap: true
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'nested',
    },
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/css/app.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/scss/app.scss'
    }
  }
},
```

Also foundation.scss is located in `bower_componenets/foundation/scss` so I have no idea why the path in the `includedPaths` property is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that's spelled correctly?  Shouldn't it be bower_components?

Comment: Well not only did I spell it wrong, I also wrote `includedPaths` instead of `includePaths`. devils in the details. thanks :) feel free to answer. if not I will later.

Comment: Problems due to typographical errors should be closed, since they typically will not help future users.

Comment: Ok. I justed voted to close it.